# How to calculate mean on second axis until row-specific column in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am looking for a fast way to calculate the mean for each row of a 2d matrix but only until a specific column. The remaining values of each row can be ignored. The column is different for each row.

In Numpy, it could be coded like this. However, I am hoping to find a solution without a for loop which also does not break the gradients.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.linspace(0, 10, 15).reshape(3,5)
cols = [2,0,4]

for row, col in enumerate(cols):
    arr[row, col+1:] = np.nan

result = np.nanmean(arr, axis=1)
```

Any suggestions?

*Edit:* Best solution I have found so far:

```
result = torch.stack([arr[i, 0:cols[i]+1].mean() for i in range(len(arr))])
```

But I would still like to avoid the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a mask:

```
t = torch.tensor(arr)
mask = torch.arange(t.shape[1]) <= torch.tensor(cols).unsqueeze(-1)

result = (t*mask).sum(1)/mask.sum(1)
```

Output:

```
tensor([0.7143, 3.5714, 8.5714], dtype=torch.float64)
```